# Is there a Mitzvah to buy from Israel?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, mitzvah, ahavat-yisrael

I'm looking to emphasize the reasons to support [Israeli businesses](http://www.u-boutique.com/). Would it be correct to add that it is a Mitzvah?

Comment: Can we assume that it is for general produce that is not under the issues of Sh'viit.

Comment: @CashCow The question doesn't mention anything about produce at all. A good answer should probably address both produce and non-produce items because produce items have lots of halachic concerns that non-produce items would not have. Shvi'it is one issue; terumah and maaser are other issues.

Comment: Buying Israeli produce during the Shemitah year is a major shemitah concern.

Comment: @CashCow it seems that the O.P. wants to know about the generality of supporting Israeli businesses. Within the answer, you can state "not if he sells shmitah produce" or whatever other halachic violations the owner may perform, if that applies. A related question might be what ownership means. Many "Israeli" companies have most of their business in the U.S. (I think Sabra foods is an example). When you buy something, how do you know if it's really "Israeli"?

Comment: T'rumah and Maaseh you can remove / redeem yourself. So it does not produce an issur on it, just a procedure you have to do before you can eat it. My own Rav says it is preferable to buy it and do this than avoid the produce. That is most years, not sh'viis.

Comment: @CashCow, I think you're missing the broader point of this question. Dov seems to want to know if it can be correctly stated that there is a Mitzvah to support Israeli businesses generally, assuming no other prohibitions come into play. I would think you might have the same objection if the business in question sold only cooked mixtures of meat and milk, or if it were a prostitution ring.

Comment: +1 for the question for me. The answer may be 'no', but the question works. Dov, welcome to Mi Yodeya.

Comment: It could be argued that buying Israeli helps others fulfill the commandment of settling the Land.

Comment: Please take this opportunity to view www.owntheholyland.com we are trying to promote the performance of Mitzvoth associated with land agricultural land ownership in Israel. Warm Regards, Zeev Zion

Answer (score 3):

The reason that supporting Israeli businesses can be seen as a mitzva is that there is an overall mitzva to buy and sell preferably from Jews (when you have the choice). This is based on a [verse in Vayikra](http://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.25.14?lang=en&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) to sell "to your fellow" which Rashi understands to mean your fellow Jew.

So if faced with the choice of buying from anyone or buying from Israel, it is more likely that buying from Israel will help you with the above mitzva. If the choice is between buying from a Jew abroad or from Israel, you can argue that when buying from Israel you help more Jews (i.e., those involved in the production, transformation, distribution of the items assuming they are manufacturing in Israel).

See [here](https://outorah.org/p/20416?) for more details.